# Show the rows to be updated and then commit

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver

Is there a way first to show the rows to be updated and then hit the commit button in DBeaver oder PGAdmin?

Comment: Replace the `UPDATE ... SET ...` part in your query with `SELECT ...`. Then you can see the rows, that will be affected by the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Alternatively: turn off autocommit, run `update ... returning *`, examine the result. If it's wrong, `rollback` otherwise `commit`

Comment: thank you for the tipp with 'returning *', that ist what I wanted!